# Bazaar branch default location

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, bazaar

I started downloading a MySQL branch using bazaar. However, I stopped the download after around 800 MB and created a shared repository in which I wish to re-download it again.
How do I remove the already downloaded 800MB file?  Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, MySQL 5.5.37 and latest  stable release of Bazaar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you interrupted the download, if you don't see a directory created then there's nothing to delete, Bazaar handled the interrupt and cleaned up after itself.

If it created something then just delete it with `rm -r`.

Comment: I interrupted using Ctrl + C and the download process exited with no dialogues.

Comment: If you see a newly created directory, delete it, if not, then there's nothing to delete